# Vertical form with CSS

Tags: html, css

How to make all inputs with the same width 100%?

if I set width 100% then input will be break on new line:

```
div > input {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <label>Label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The desired result ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rk1vb7u/)):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: They move to a new line because *you tell them to*. Setting the width of an element to 100% means it will occupy 100% width.

Comment: just set the width of the label and set the width of the input accordingly. 20% / 80% or something. there's no other way

Comment: Maybe try to suppress any margin or padding around the input tag and suppress the padding on your div's (wrapper and inside) explicitely.

Comment: and if you decide to set it to a specific width AND apply margin/padding, go for `box-sizing: border box;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper input {
    width: 90%;
}
```

You cannot make it 100% without a new line because the Label will take some space of the screen. Remaining portion you can allot for the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/2rk1vb7u/1/)**

Just remove the `float` statement, and make both the `label` and `input` `display: inline-block`.

```
.wrapper div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div > input, div > label {
    display: inline-block;
}
div > input {
    width: 77%;
}

div > label {
    width: 20%;
}
```

You can change the width of the `input` fields and/or the `labels`, but I think `width: 77%` is the highest value possible for the input fields (with the width of the labels set to 20%) to still display inline.

**EDIT:**

Do note that using CSS selectors based on HTML tagnames is not the ideal way of doing this. A better way is to give all `labels` and `inputs` a class (f.e. `class="lbl"` and `class="inp"` respectively), and selecting those, like underneath:

```
...
.lbl, .inp {
    display: inline-block;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
.wrapper{width:100%; display:block}
.wrapper lable{width:30%; display:inline-block; position:relative}
.wrapper input{width:70%; display:inline-block; position:relative}
</pre>
```